# Python generator for paged API resource

Tags: python, generator

So I have this RESTful API with a collection `people`, which can be called like this:

```
http://example.com/people?lastname=smith
```

Which returns a JSON response like this:

```
    {
      "page": 0,
      "next": 1,
      "total": 5000000,
      "people": [
        { 
          "firstname": "John",
          "lastname": "Smith",
          "age": 32
        },
        { 
          "firstname": "Adam",
          "lastname": "Smith",
          "age": 84
        },
        ...
    }
```

I want to write a Python generator that will yield each person from the response and when it gets to the last person, if there is a next page, it will make the request for the next page with `http://example.com/people?lastname=smith&page=1` and continue iterating over the results seamlessly. The resulting class call would be as simple as:

```
    client = PeopleClient("http://example.com/people")
    smiths = client.get_people_by_last_name("smith")
```

Where I would then be able to iterate over every "Smith" in `smiths`; through all 5 million, if necessary.

Any ideas on how to make this happen or if it is even possible?

### Update

Using the answer from @ali-afshar as a guide, this implementation should work for the hypothetical REST API:

```
    import requests

    class PeopleClient:
        def __init__(self, url):
            self._url = url

        def _get_people(self, **kwargs):
            return requests.get(self._url, params=kwargs)

        def get_people_by_last_name(self, lastname):
            current_page = 0
            while current_page >= 0:
                result = self._get_people(lastname=lastname, page=current_page)
                for person in result.get("people", []):
                    yield person

                current_page = result.get("next", -1)
```

Comment: You could use [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/) package and in built json package to parse the JSON. And then loop through all names. When you've finished, request for next page. If it returns 404 then stop else continue the above. After you've mined everything, just iterate over this list.

Comment: @Vineet Thought the whole point of using generators was not to process the entire bulk of the dataset prior to iterating over it. I used the 5 million number in my example to illustrate exactly why you wouldn't make all these requests up front.

Comment: Why didn't anyone see that I was already aware of Python Generators and that I had zero intention of pulling all the results into memory first? Thought I made it pretty clear by using phrases like "I want to write a Python generator" and "yield" in my question.

Comment: @jeremyswitzer @ali-afshar if we `yield result.get("people", [])` multiple people directly will there be any performance improvement though I agree we need to change the api consuming the generator as well for accepting multiple people

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Short of writing your code for you, you want to take advantage of Python's generators, rather than realizing the whole set as a list. This way you can start using the results immediately and only perform paged requests when you get to the end of a page.

```
for person in PeopleClient("http://ex..").get_people_by_last_name("smith"):
    # Do something with the person
```

Secondly, your implementation of the actual request should take a page parameter which you can increment, and which can be called by the wrapper generator.

```
def get_people_page(name, page):
    # Perform the HTTP request, using page=page
```

The generator itself will be something like:

```
def get_all_people(name):
    page = 0
    has_more = 1
    while has_more:
        for person in get_people_page(name, page):
            yield person
        page += 1
        has_more = # calculate has more by whether you have a next link
                   # or whether the results set is empty
                   # or whether you get an error
```

Comment: Thanks. Though I'll have to figure out something to expose whether there is a next link in the response. The get_people_page function only returns the collection.

Comment: I updated the answer with other ways of seeing if you have more.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my generator solution which I think is a touch cleaner, and when working with a specified `per_page` it saves you an extra needless request.

```
def get_all(per_page=100):
    page = 0
    while True:
        items = self.api.get(per_page=per_page, page=page)

        for item in items:
            yield item

        if len(items) < per_page:
            break

        page += 1

all_items = list(get_all())
```

The `self.api.get()` must accept a `page` and `per_page` param.